# UitableView Programmatically Custom Cells width

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

hello I'm trying to change the width of the cells in a tableview programaticallly I have this code initially

`

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
    [self.theTableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(100, 0, 200.0, 768.0);                         
    self.theTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    theTableView.delegate = self;
    theTableView.dataSource = self;
    [self.view addSubview:theTableView];
    self.title = @"TableView";
```

}
`
works one way but the problem is that the cells are duplicated as shown below

[image](http://i47.tinypic.com/sbsocw.png)

thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

Cell's placed inside a tableview should autosize to the width of the tableview. In your code you are setting the width of the tableview to 200. Therefore the cells should be 200 as well. Are you using a custom cell or just the default UITableViewCell? If you are using a custom cell and setting the cell's width to something different than the tableview width it may be causing the duplication.